# How to share on facebook using graph api in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want to share a link in my application.I didnt find any api for sharing link in graph api.

What is the difference between sharing and posting in facebook?How can I perform sharing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried with the samples which provided by the facebook developers https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You can post to wall on facebook using this code:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message","YOUR_MESSAGE");
parameters.putString("link", "ANY_LINK");
String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,
                    "POST");
```

Also to upload an image, you can use this code:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message","YOUR_MESSAGE");
parameters.putString("caption","ANY_CAPTION");
parameters.putByteArray("picture", "IMAGE_LINK");
String response = facebook.request("me/photos", parameters,
                    "POST");
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: what is the difference between sharing and posting

Comment: If you put your own content then you can say posting. but in case of sharing, there can be a any link or other user's content. so if you post a link then you can also called it sharing a LINK.